# Make django select a list of related objects

Tags: django, orm, django-models, django-queryset

I have a model like this:

```
class Issue(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, null=True, blank=True)
    key = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, blank=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=400)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    createdByUser = models.ForeignKey(User)
    creationDate = models.DateTimeField()
    updatedDate = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    trackerURL = models.URLField(null=True, blank=True)
    is_feedback = models.BooleanField()
    is_public_suggestion = models.BooleanField()

class IssueWatch(models.Model):
    issue = models.ForeignKey(Issue)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    reason = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=False, blank=False)
```

Full code is here:
https://github.com/freedomsponsors/www.freedomsponsors.org/blob/master/djangoproject/core/models.py

This is for a system similar to an issue tracker. There are `Issues` and a user can watch an Issue (`IssueWatch`) to receive email updates.

I want to make a query that will return a list of Issues that a user is watching. Something like:

```
IssueWatch.objects.select('issue').filter(user=17)
```

Of course, there's no such a "select" method like the one I'd like to use above.

Is there any way I can make Django return a lazy collection of Issue (and not IssueWatch) objects?

--------------- UPDATE -----------

I tried reading `user.issue_set.all()` and it works. 
Now I'm confused. Why does User get a issue_set? 
What if I had created another model that let the user, say, favorite issues, like:

```
class IssueFavorite(models.Model):
    issue = models.ForeignKey(Issue)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

What would `issue_set` mean then?

--------------- UPDATE2 -----------

Duh, I found the answer.
issue_set refers to the issues created by the user (because of attribute: `Issue.createdByUser`)
That's not the issue list I want.

Comment: You've set up an IssueWatch model just for collecting this information, I don't know of any way you can get a list of Issues without having to go through these, unless you have some other table that is linking users with individual Issues.

Comment: deleting dense thinking

Comment: I'm deleting this comment and editting the question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, if I'm understanding the question, you want to select all of the issues being watched by a particular user? That would be done with the following:

```
Issue.objects.filter(issuewatch__user=17)
```

[Source](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships)

Comment: I think I should get a bonus for including the source ;)

Answer (score 2):

Just a simple `filter` will work. Select queries allow reverse relations. So:

```
Issue.objects.filter(issuewatch__user = 17)
```

Comment: I'm gonna flip the coin to see who gets the green flag... :-)

Comment: I'll upvote this one to make up for my getting the checkmark :)